# Java help? '(' '[' expected

Tags: java

Can somebody please point out where the extra '(' or '[' should be please?

```
private void pickItem(Command command)
{
    String item =  command.getSecondWord();
    Item newItem;

    Room r= thePlayer.getRoom();
    newItem = r.getItem;

    if (newItem == null)
        System.out.println("That item is not here");
    else {
        inventory.add(new Item);
        r.removeItem(item);
        System.out.println("Picked Up:" + item);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can somebody please point out where the extra '(' or '[' should be please?" -- Your IDE or compiler certainly can, can't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` needs parentheses:

```
inventory.add(new Item());
```